# Weird group_by + mutate + which.max behavior

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm running into unexpected behavior with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(date = c("2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", 
      "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", 
      "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", 
      "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", 
      "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", 
      "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", 
      "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", 
      "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", 
      "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", 
      "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-02", 
      "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", 
      "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", 
      "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", 
      "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", 
      "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", 
      "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", 
      "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", 
      "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", 
      "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", 
      "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", 
      "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", 
      "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", 
      "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", 
      "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", 
      "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", 
      "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", 
      "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", 
      "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", 
      "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-04", 
      "2016-05-04", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", 
      "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", 
      "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", 
      "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", 
      "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", 
      "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", 
      "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", 
      "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", 
      "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", 
      "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-06", 
      "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", 
      "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", 
      "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", 
      "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", 
      "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", 
      "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", 
      "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", 
      "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", 
      "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06", 
      "2016-05-06", "2016-05-06"), abc = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
         NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
         NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
         NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 20, 20, 16, 
         14, 9, 8, 6, 5, 5, 6, 7, 13, 24, 52, 65, 68, 66, 65, 58, 47, 
         21, 6, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
         1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 19, 19, 15, 11, 8, 8, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
         9, 17, 31, 43, 49, 52, 52, 47, 32, 21, 6, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 14, 
         14, 14, 15, 18, 18, 14, 14, 14, 15, 19, 29, 46, 58, 62, 69, 71, 
         67, 56, 40, 25, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
         2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 18, 18, 14, 12, 9, 7, 5, 
         4, 5, 5, 7, 9, 17, 30, 36, 49, 52, 54, 54, 42, 32, 15, 5, 1)), 
     class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -240L), .Names = c("date", "abc"))


df %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(peak_max_index = as.numeric(which.max(as.numeric(abc))))
```

What I would expect this to return is `peak_max_index` that's `41` for all rows where `date` is `2016-05-04`. But strangely `peak_max_index` is `NA` instead. Even more strangely, if you kick out all rows where `date` is `2016-05-03` before you run the `dplyr` commands, the result is entirely correct. Is this a bug?

Comment: Did you try `df %>% group_by(date) %>% mutate(peak_max_index = as.numeric(which.max(as.numeric(abc)))) %>% filter(date == '2016-05-04')`? This is showing that the first part is doing the right thing. What is `packageVersion('dplyr')` show?

Comment: That gives me the same result. Package version is `0.4.3`

Comment: So, what part of the result is weird? I saved the result of your command into `df` and subset this way `df[df$date == '2016-05-04', ]` and still get 41 for all rows.

Comment: BTW - there are some bugs in `dplyr` 0.4.3 (unrelated to this issue) and so I use dev version `0.4.3.9001`.

Comment: For the same subset, I get `NA' for all rows. May have to try the dev version.

Comment: I also get `NA` for all rows for that subset using package version `0.4.3`. A bug in this version, maybe?

Comment: yeah, I won't use `0.4.3`. It bit me on many things.

Comment: Works fine for me in the latest dev version as well.

Comment: BTW - `distinct()` behaves differently in dev version (requires explicit specification of column names). I reported this problem and Hadley said this will be reverted. Just know that this will bite you in dev version.

Comment: Works fine for me on `0.4.3.9000`.

Answer (score -1):

You are evaluating `NA's` in your formula `which.max()`. Just eliminate the `NA's` with `!is.na()`.

```
df %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    mutate(peak_max_index = max(df$abc[!is.na(df$abc)]))
```

Comment: I am not. There are no `NA`s in `abc` in the group that produces the `NA` and I'm looking for `which.max` not `max`.

Comment: Then you will need to use `aggregate(. ~ date, df, FUN = max, na.action = NULL)`. You can then subset the max values into `df` where the dates are equal or use `merge(df, df.agg, by = "date")`.

Comment: That still wouldn't give me the result I want, namely the index of the first of the maximal values.

Comment: Then using dplyr's summarise and merge should do it: `df %>%
    group_by(date) %>% summarise(as.numeric(which.max(as.numeric(abc)))) %>% merge(df, by = "date")`