# Winners within pairs; or vector-valued group_by mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to assess which unit in a pair is the "winner". `group_by() %>% mutate()` is close to the right thing, but it's not quite there.  in particular

`dat %>% group_by(pair) %>% mutate(winner = ifelse(score[1] > score[2], c(1, 0), c(0, 1)))` doesn't work.

The below does, but is clunky with an intermediate summary data frame. Can we improve this?

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(343)
# units within pairs get scores
dat <-
  data_frame(pair = rep(1:3, each = 2),
             unit = rep(1:2, 3),
             score = rnorm(6))

# figure out who won in each pair
summary_df <- 
  dat %>%
  group_by(pair) %>%
  summarize(winner = which.max(score))

# merge back and determine whether each unit won
dat <- 
  left_join(dat, summary_df, "pair") %>%
  mutate(won = as.numeric(winner == unit))
dat
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>    pair  unit  score winner   won
#>   <int> <int>  <dbl>  <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1 -1.40       2     0
#> 2     1     2  0.523      2     1
#> 3     2     1  0.142      1     1
#> 4     2     2 -0.847      1     0
#> 5     3     1 -0.412      1     1
#> 6     3     2 -1.47       1     0
```

Created on 2018-09-26 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

maybe related to [Weird group_by + mutate + which.max behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37013514/weird-group-by-mutate-which-max-behavior)

Comment: `dat %>% group_by(pair) %>% mutate(won = rank(score) - 1)`

Comment: @Henrik Gah, that's so much better! Sigh.

Comment: @Henrik, that's nice. If you make this an answer, will accept! I think the general thing is having a function that returns a vector of the right length.  e.g. `my_fun <- function(X){
  coin <- rbinom(1, 1, pnorm(X[1] - X[2])) == 1
  if(coin) c(1, 0) else c(0, 1)
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rank`:

```
dat %>% group_by(pair) %>% mutate(won = rank(score) - 1)
```

More for fun (and slightly faster), using the outcome of the comparison (`score[1] > score[2]`) to index a vector with 'won alternatives' :

```
dat %>% group_by(pair) %>%
  mutate(won = c(0, 1, 0)[1:2 + (score[1] > score[2])])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(pair) %>% 
  mutate(won = score == max(score),
         winner = unit[won == TRUE]) %>% 
   # A tibble: 6 x 5
   # Groups:   pair [3]
   pair  unit  score won   winner
  <int> <int>  <dbl> <lgl>  <int>
1     1     1 -1.40  FALSE      2
2     1     2  0.523 TRUE       2
3     2     1  0.142 TRUE       1
4     2     2 -0.847 FALSE      1
5     3     1 -0.412 TRUE       1
6     3     2 -1.47  FALSE      1
```